# Waiting until an item arrives in a protected object

Tags: synchronization, task, blocking, ada

Okay, Ada tasking is quite new and confusing to me. I have a classic problem with a protected object that stores events by IDs as key. The idea is that a producer task fills it with incoming events and one or more consumer tasks need to wait *until* an event of a given id arrives, i.e., they should block until it is stored in the map, and then return that event.

Here is the structure so far:

```ada
 package Reply_Storage is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps
 (Key_Type     => Command_Id_Type,
  Element_Type => Event_Type);

 protected type Reply_Queue is
      procedure Put (Event : Event_Type);
      entry Take (Id : Command_Id_Type; Event : out Event_Type);
   private
      Storage : Reply_Storage.Map;
 end Reply_Queue;

 protected body Reply_Queue is
      procedure Put (Event : Event_Type) is
         Id : Command_Id_Type := Event_Command_Id (Event);
      begin
         Storage.Insert (Id, Event);
      end Put;
      entry Take (Id : Command_Id_Type; Event : out Event_Type) 
       when not Storage.Is_Empty is
      begin
         if Storage.Contains(Id) then
           Event := Storage.Element (Id);
            Storage.Delete (Id);
         end if;
      end Take;
 end Reply_Queue;
```

Basically, instead of *when not Storage.Is_Empty*, I would need a barrier *when Storage.Contains(Id)* in the body of entry *Take*. This is not allowed, of course, because barriers are checked independently of the entry call.

But how to achieve the desired synchronization?

Comment: Sounds like you need an entry family ([RM 9.5.2(20)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-5-2.html#I4077)), which is kind of like an array of entries (and I think at least GNAT implements them as such)

Comment: IIRC barriers are evaluated after completion of procedures/entries, so your problem is not that they're evaluated independently, but that you can't use the argument Id on the barrier condition.

Comment: Hit enter too fast. I wanted to add that if you only have a consumer you could perhaps manage some workaround by requeuing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you need is an entry family (only works for discrete types), like this:

```ada
package Reply_Storage is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps
 (Key_Type     => Command_Id_Type,
  Element_Type => Event_Type);

 protected type Reply_Queue is
      procedure Put (Event : Event_Type);
      entry Take (Command_Id_Type) (Event : out Event_Type); -- entry family
   private
      Storage : Reply_Storage.Map;
 end Reply_Queue;

 protected body Reply_Queue is
      procedure Put (Event : Event_Type) is
         Id : Command_Id_Type := Event_Command_Id (Event);
      begin
         Storage.Insert (Id, Event);
      end Put;
      entry Take (for Id in Command_Id_Type) (Event : out Event_Type) -- entry family
       when Storage.Contains(Id) is -- family designator (entry index) in barrier
      begin
         Event := Storage.Element (Id);
         Storage.Delete (Id);
      end Take;
 end Reply_Queue;
```

Comment: For a comparison between entry families and Ada 95's “more powerful” **requeue** (mentioned in c.l.ada), cf. [Rationale 95](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-9.html#2), explaining “preference control”. This part of the rationale is continuing [Rationale 83](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83rat/html/ratl-13-02.html#13.2.11) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to work, but there is weird curiosity. *Command_Id_Type* was originally a simple subtype of Natural and with that it refused to compile because of a static constraint check failure. Defining it as *Command_Id_Type is new Integer range 0 .. Integer'Last-1;* works, but gcc spits out a number of strange messages:  *In function `bham__connection_handlerTKB':
bham.adb:(.text+0x1300a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.bss'* and at many other places. What do they mean?

Comment: Rather than exploring the implementation's way of handling an enormous amount of queues (perhaps a job for the implementer), I'd consider the number of actual Command IDs of the problem at hand, and define a type reflecting that. Using `Natural` or `Integer'Last - 1`, makes this (a) dependent on the implementation (~`2**15`, ~`2**31`, or ~`2**63`), and (b) looses the aforementioned preciseness. So, perhaps `range 1000 .. 1450` or some such?

Comment: That's good advice. Unfortunately in this case Command IDs are consecutive numbers for which I need a large space, not a small fixed set of numbers. In the current GNAT, a modular 2 ** 24 integer type works for entry families. It's probably enough for my application, but the implementation-dependency of this solution indeed bothers me and I will explore a requeue solution when I have the time. In any case, egilhh's reply prefectly answers my question, as I left it unclear how many command ids there actually are.